# mongodb query with a Variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb

If I am using query on the shell it is working. If I do query in my script (same) its not working.
can you please let me know if I am missing anything.

```
db.Names.find( {Fail: 1})
```

The above code is working in mongodbshell and its printing all the entries in the colection with Fail=1

when I try sme code in my reactjs application (javascript) its failing.

```
mongodb.db("maindatabase")
            .collection("Names").find({ Fail: 1 }).asArray()
            .then(Names => {
                this.setState({ Names });
            });
```

The above code is always 0. 
is it I am missing anything ? (or) are there any extra steps I need to do

I tried `var result=1`

```
mongodb.db("maindatabase")
                .collection("Names").find({ Fail: result }).asArray()
                .then(Names1 => {
                    this.setState({ Names1 });
                });
```

This is also not working.

Comment: what plugin you are using for `mongodb`? also the backend is `node` right?

Comment: I am using mongodb-atlas. no node.

Comment: for application I am using mongodb-stitch to connect to my atlas

Comment: you consoled `Names1`

Comment: what errors or warning it gives

Comment: There are no Errors (or) warnings Akshya. it does not print anything when used in js. wondering if I am doing wring in declaring

Comment: Sravan, its a typo I have the same values

Comment: Do you connect `maindatabase` from mongodb-atlas?

Comment: yes from mongodb-atlas

Comment: Please let meknow if any info is needed